# Adding random noise to an ill-posed problem

Tags: linear-algebra, weak-convergence, random, regularization, condition-number

Suppose I have found a (finite) solution $x$ to an ill-posed problem, e.g.
\begin{equation}
   b = A x
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a $N\times N$ matrix with a large condition number, $b$ is a vector collecting $N$ observations. I was wondering if it could be analytically proven why adding a random noise to $b$ of the form
\begin{equation}
   b_i \rightarrow \tilde b_i = b_i + \varepsilon \eta_i\,, \quad \varepsilon \ll \vert b_i \vert\,, \quad \langle \eta_i \rangle = 0\,, \quad \langle \eta_i \eta_j \rangle = \delta(i-j)
\end{equation}
causes the reconstructed solution $\tilde x$ of the problem
\begin{equation}
   \tilde b = A \tilde x
\end{equation}
to be divergent or substantially different than $x$.

Suppose now that a regulation to the matrix $A$ of the form
\begin{equation}
   A \rightarrow A + \lambda \mathbb{1}
\end{equation}
is applied. How and why does the above argument change?